# Calculate with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum the values of my number inputs. I want to get all the input values and
sum them.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="20" id="number-<?php echo $item_slug; ?>" class="number-label" value="1" />
```

And my jquery:

```
function itensSoma2() {
    $('.number-label').each(function() {
        var soma2 = 0;
        soma2 += parseInt($(this).val());
        console.log(soma2);
    });
}
```

But all i get in my console is alot of number 1!!

Comment: Move your variable "soma2" outside of the each functio, you are making it equal to 0 every time you enter the each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare your variable outside the loop:

```
function itensSoma2() {
    var soma2 = 0;
    $('.number-label').each(function() {
        soma2 += parseInt($(this).val());
        console.log(soma2);
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.value` is faster :) +1 either way